# Django foreign key constraint on drop even thou on_delete=CASCADE

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I can't see what's wrong with this,

```py
class Agenda(models.Model):
    ...

class AgendaResource(PolymorphicModel):
    agenda = models.ForeignKey(
        Agenda, related_name="resources", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    comment = models.TextField(null=True)

class PreemptiveMeasureResource(AgendaResource):
    resource = models.ForeignKey(
        PreemptiveMeasure, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True
    )
    ...
```

When I try to delete an agenda, i.e. `Agenda.objects.get(pk=2).delete()` I get this problem:

```sh
update or delete on table "school_health_agendaresource" violates foreign key constraint "school_health_preemp_agendaresource_ptr_i_222e2e2c_fk_school_he" on table "school_health_preemptivemeasureresource"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) is still referenced from table "school_health_preemptivemeasureresource"
```

What is it I don't understand? I'm guessing it's something to do with the inheritance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with `django-polymorphic`, see issues [here](https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic/issues/34), [here](https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic/issues/229) and [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23076).

You can try adding below to your `AgendaResource` model as a workaround:

```
class AgendaResource(PolymorphicModel):
    ...
    non_polymorphic = models.Manager()

    class Meta
        base_manager_name = 'non_polymorphic'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me a tonne of time, for some reason I wasn't stumbling onto the right track even thou I googled `Polymorphic inheritance delete`